# Which MacBook screen should I buy?

Tags: macbook-pro, repair

My wife broke the screen on her MacBook. I want to buy a replacement and try to put it in myself. How do I determine the correct screen to buy? It is a 13.3" screen. But, the computer is several years old.

I am not asking for a product recommendation. I am going to buy the official Apple screen. I just read that not every screen fits every MacBook. For instance, one site said I have to worry about which wireless antenna I have. Another said I have to worry about unibody or not. But, I don't know the various specs of the MacBook my wife has. I tried to look up the serial number online, but it doesn't list the model number when I do that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to identify which model is my Mac?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/126715/how-to-identify-which-model-is-my-mac)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds to me like you need to identify your Mac model more than anything else. Give a try [How to identify which model is my Mac?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/126715/how-to-identify-which-model-is-my-mac/126716)

Once you know your precise model, you may want to go to [ifixit.com](http://www.ifixit.com/Device/Mac) to identify the precise piece number you’re looking for.